# Please unfreeze the Docker chat

Tags: support, chat

I neglected the Docker chat thinking that owner access was enough to unfreeze it, but now see that I would need to be an Stack Overflow moderator to do that. Please unfreeze this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76919/docker

Comment: I this really a Hot Meta Posts type of item? :)

Comment: @R.Richards Yes, others would get to know about the procedure which they need to follow while unfreezing a chat.

Comment: ...and its frozen again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Done, I went ahead and unfroze the room for you. Keep in mind, you can always try to ping a SO mod in another chatroom if this were to happen again.

Comment: ... Or custom chat flag the last message in the room and ask...

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, that too. :)

Comment: Thanks. I quietly queried TL without pinging anyone. I was hoping to be less obtrusive since this was relatively low priority.

Comment: @BMitch No worries, happy to help.

Comment: @JonClements Is that still an ok way of asking for an unfreeze? The text on the dialog says "Please do not use this feature for anything other than informing moderators of **serious** issues that require their attention." - is that just to prevent silly abuses of it for personal reasons (eg. during a disagreement)? Do requests for unfreezing count as a valid reason to use it?

Comment: @sundar it's fine. I wouldn't bother if it was a really old room with no activity for ages that has been frozen reasonably, but if it just so happens it's a room that hasn't been active recently but will be and has been etc... go for it.

Comment: @sundar just make sure to provide a good reason why a moderator should oblige and unfreeze the room.

Comment: @JonClements It's the latter, just been inactive recently and gaining some interest again. I'll mention that in the mod message, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Taryn, Is there a room where moderators are approachable? I want to ask one to unfreeze https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170911/discussion-between-plasmacel-and-royi as we want to continue discussion on the same subject. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi As Jon says [in the first comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360733/please-unfreeze-the-docker-chat/360734?noredirect=1#comment540412_360734), you can always custom flag a chat message.

Comment: It's frozen again...